# javascript selction list, show options in loop

Tags: javascript

i am just trying to do a loop in a selection list. selection list is about the month, it should include 12 month options. i have got things shown below:

```
function selectMonth(){
     var month = document.getElementsById('Month');
     for(var i = 1; i < 12; i++)
     { 
          month.options[month.options.length] = new Option ('i');

     }
}
```

I also try the code like:

```
function selectMonth(){
for(var i = 1; i < 12; i++)
{
    var month = new Option(i, i);

}
}
```

but the code above is not work, anyone know why?

Comment: Does not work = ? You must explain a bit here.

Comment: Use your browser's developer console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: replace `getElementsById` by `getElementById`. 
Also, replace `new Option ('i');` by `new Option (i);` and `< 12` by `<= 12`

```
function selectMonth(){
     var month = document.getElementById('Month');
     for(var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
     { 
          month.options[month.options.length] = new Option (i);
     }
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvDJm/)